# Let employees buy products via POS

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I would like to use the odoo POS also for internal use. Employees should be able to buy products for themselves. All of the costs should be charged via the payslip of every employee.

Example: A is an employee of my company X. A buys a coke (2$) from the POS. B is chief  of HR at X and wants to generate the payslip of A to send him his loan (100$) for the month. Odoo should now calculate and sum up all POS expenses and then show B that A gets a loan of 98$.

I would probably do some adjustments with custom modules, however would it even be possible to set an employee as the customer in odoo?

Comment: Customer is always `res.partner` in odoo, what you can do is to create relation between `hr.employee` model and `res.partner` model so that whenever `hr.employee` record is created, a `res.partner` is also created with same informations, that you can use to sale in POS, and to calculate expense.

Comment: @arryph Thank you. That’s also what I thought. But it should be possible to create a customer and connect it with the employee by storing a connection in the employee profile. When the loan is calculated odoo would then use the customer connected to the employee to take the expenses into account

Comment: By default `hr.employee` has `Many2one` connection with `res.users` by field `user_id`, `res.users` has `Many2one` connection with `res.partner` by field `partner_id`. But if you want to make relation between  `hr.employee` and  `res.partner` you have to modify.

Comment: My plan is the following: I add the new field connected_customer to the employee model. I have to customize the payslip and loan features. That’s obvious. There I will use the made connection of the employee to get all the expenses of the customer (although it’s the same person in real life). When the loan is calculated I will cut that amount from the loan.

Comment: sure. sounds about right. let me know if need any help.